# Not getting Cascadia Code PL in Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-10, posh-git

I wanted to get started with posh and oh-my-posh so I installed them according to this article. [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/powerline-setup). I got the theme but the edges didn't had that arrow(that coolness).

I then downloaded the windows terminal and edited the setting.json there with

```
"fontFace": "Cascadia Code PL"
```

So it got the desired result of posh in there.

Now the only problem currently is how to change this in windows powershell. I integrated the powershell in my vs code so there also I was not able to find this theme(or desired result). All I could find is the color but not the arrow and that fancy icons or what the jargon is.

Please help. I want my powershell to have posh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, there are two parts to the question.

#### Changing the PowerShell Window Font

To do this, right-click your PowerShell window and head to "Properties"

[image: PowerShell Right Click Menu]

There, you can choose the header "Font" and change your font to Cascadia Code PL".

[image: Font Properties of PowerShell]

This should fix the problem. If you still experience some weird characters, you might need to install a [Nerd Font](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts) instead.

#### Changing the VS Code Terminal Font

To use the font in the VS Code Terminal, head to Settings.
[image: You can open Settings by clicking the gear-icon on the bottom left.]

Searching for "integrated terminal font family" should bring up the setting you need to edit. Here, add your font 'Cascadia Code PL' on the very front of the setting and save.

[image: Fonts are separated by commas and the setting is called "Terminal>Integrated:Font Family"]

You should now be able to open a terminal and use the PL prompt.

Comment: Thank you it worked. Not related to this but does it happen to everyone that you do something and it doesn't work and after some time you try the same thing again and it works :)